# state_enabled="false" doesn't work, but the anothers work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-selector

Hello I have the following code:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="#FF0000"
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button_disable"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button_shadow"
        android:bottom="4px" />

</selector>
```

**white_button_disable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <corners android:radius="28dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

If the button is clicked it shows the white_button, if the buttons don't press it shows white_buttons_shadow.

But if the button is disabled (enabled = "false") it doesn't work, and shows white_button_shadow

Any idea?

Comment: on the 3rd item try adding the property android:state_enabled = "true"

Comment: this doesn't work correctly, the disable button is showed but whitout color instead of a red color

Comment: And whats your drawable/white_button_disable

Comment: just edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it

```
 <item android:state_enabled="false"
     android:drawable="@drawable/white_button_disable"/>
```

Your `android:color="#FF0000"` is breaking the selector.

Remove it and you should be fine.